# Доступ к параметрам базового класса при наследовании шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, шаблоны-с++, наследование

У шаблонного базового класса есть protected член data, в шаблонном классе наследнике есть функция от экземлпяра базового класса, в которой мне нужно использовать data, но компилятор выдает error: 'data' is a protected member of 'State'. Но ведь так и есть и в этом нет ошибки, доступ к ней должен быть.

```
template <typename T>
class State
{
protected:
    std::valarray<T> data;
public:
    State(std::valarray<T> d): data(d) {}

    State<T> virtual append(State<T> ds)
    {
        State<T>::data += ds.data;
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class NewState : public State<T>
{
public:
    NewState(std::valarray<T> d): State<T>(d) {}

    State<T> append(State<T> ds) override
    {
        State<T>::data += ds.data; //error
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Пробовал через указатели обращаться - тоже самое выдало.
Компилятор clang++ -std=c++17

Неужели совсем нельзя подружить наследование с шаблонами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шаблоны тут ни при чем. Рассмотрим пример без шаблонов:

```
class A
{
protected:
    int a;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void doit(A x) { cout << x.a; }
};
```

результат тот же.

Вы можете в производном классе обращаться к `protected` членам базового, но только *в своем объекте*, грубо говоря, через `this`. Это не значит обращение к `protected` членам базового любого объекта базового класса!

У вас в

```
State<T> append(State<T> ds) override
{
    State<T>::data += ds.data; //error
```

`ds` — совсем посторонний объект, не имеющий отношения к текущему, так что его защищенные члены для вас недоступны.

Comment: Ох. Совсем забыл, что это так работает в пределах одного класса. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Harry объяснил, в чем проблема. А вот как чинить, если `protected:` убирать не хочется:

```
State<T>::data += ds.*&NewState::data;
```

Формируем указатель-на-член, и сразу применяем его к нужному типу.

Причем указатель требуется писать именно через `NewState::`, а не `State<T>::` (не скомпилируется), хотя в типе результата все равно будет фигурировать `State<T>::*`.

Comment: Только не дай Бог при этом добавить в `NewState` поле с именем `data`...

Comment: @Harry Ага, тогда ошибка компиляции и поле родителя уже никак не достать.

Comment: Спасибо! Хотя кажется странным, что так делать нельзя, но если очень хочется, то можно. xD

Comment: @СтепанЛапшин Я вам больше скажу, можно угнать любое приватное поле из любого класса, только там метод чуть хитрее: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oKdoqqY3Y